# how do I align center all the elements in my div including an angular material input select?

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to have all my elements aligned center in a container, but the material input won't move.
Here's a sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mat-select-dynamic-data-binding-in-angu-gzepgb?file=index.html

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: If you inspect it you see that it is aligned, but it does not look like it because there is still an small spacer for the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because of the MatFormField's height!

Your css is perfect, the problem is that the MatFormField uses a height to show errors below of itself

I changed the height in your stackblitz: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mat-select-dynamic-data-binding-in-angu-x7xjxv?file=app/ex1.html)

Comment: how did you change that?

Comment: It's in the html ex1.html line 9

Answer (score 0):

This is because of that component encapsulation, also material has some priority classes defined it. Ideal solution will be here.

```
.container::ng-deep * {
  align-items: center !important;
}
```